# TabBar height is too big

Tags: swift, objective-c, xcode, uitabbar, tabbar

can please someone explain, why do I have such a huge TabBar when I create it programmatically?

```
viewControllers = [
        createNavController(for: AssetViewController(), title: NSLocalizedString("Search", comment: ""), image: UIImage(systemName: "magnifyingglass")!),
        createNavController(for: AssetViewController(), title: NSLocalizedString("Home", comment: ""), image: UIImage(systemName: "house")!),
        createNavController(for: AssetViewController(), title: NSLocalizedString("Profile", comment: ""), image: UIImage(systemName: "person")!)
    ]
func createNavController(for viewController: UIViewController, title: String, image: UIImage) -> UIViewController {
    viewController.tabBarItem.title = "Wallet"
    viewController.tabBarItem.image = image

    return viewController
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

check your Navigation view controller frame (height constraint)

and

check your tabar constraint
example:
self.tabBar.frame = CGRect(x: frame.origin.x, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height - 80, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 80)